# Neural Networks: Minimal, open source example with exhaustive training data?

Tags: c++, c, neural-network

I am currently searching for a neural network (toy) example, that I might optimize using GPU kernels. I need

- clean & minimal code (no fancy optimizations, max. a few thousand sloc)
- **ample** testing data
- C/C++ open source

Does anybody has an adequate hint?

There's a bunch of examples on the net, but with insufficient testing data (there's no sense in GPU-optimizing code, that executes in a few seconds anyway)

Answer (score 3):

> clean & minimal code (no fancy
>   optimizations, max. a few thousand
>   sloc) C/C++ open source

The venerable [Neural Networks at your Fingertips](http://www.neural-networks-at-your-fingertips.com/) (or [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20040326060554/http://www.neural-networks-at-your-fingertips.com/) ) is written very cleanly in C, it's very easy to play with and contains implementations for a number of 'popular' architectures (since you don't specify what neural network architecture(s) you're interested in).

> ample testing data

You can find ample testing data (amongst other places) at the [UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/).

Comment: I was aware of these, I was just hoping there might be some ready-to-use example that doesn't require me to write a parser for the testing data. Anyway thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @xrismf What kind of data are you thinking about?

Comment: I've started to work on the BOLTZMAN example from your first link since it generates it's training data dynamically and seems well suited for paralizing. Thanks again for the hint.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the library is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked 7 years previous to my seeing it. Presently there is the [OpenNN](http://www.opennn.net) project which would seem to meet the criteria. It is entirely in C++. There is a good amount of [examples](https://github.com/orian/opennn/tree/master/examples) on github. The [main project page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opennn/) is on SourceForge, however. I don't think their github is kept as up to date.